# Get Settings with id of 1? Laravel5.4*

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

Uses table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('surename');
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('country')->nullable();
        $table->string('postcode')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->string('facebook_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('linkedin_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('twitter_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Setting table:

```
 Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('value');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Setting_user (Pivot table):

```
 Schema::create('setting_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('setting_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('setting_id')->references('id')->on('settings');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Categories table:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Setting_category (pivot table):

```
 Schema::create('setting_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->integer('setting_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('setting_id')->references('id')->on('settings');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

In my User model this I have a belongsToMany relationship:

```
public function settings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Setting::class, 'setting_user', 'user_id','setting_id')->with('category');
}
```

And in my setting model:

protected $table = 'settings';

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Categories::class,'id');
}
```

When I access it like so:

```
public function settings()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    return $user->settings()->with('category')->first();
}
```

This is the result I get:

```
{"id":1,"value":"87658675.jpg","created_at":"2017-07-04 00:00:00","updated_at":null,"pivot":{"user_id":1,"setting_id":1},"category":[{"id":1,"name":"avatar","created_at":"2017-07-06 00:00:00","updated_at":null}]}
```

How can I get only the settings with category->id == 1 ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only settings for specified user and specified category, use `whereHas()`:

```
public function settings()
{
    $categoryId = 1;
    $userId = 1;

    return Settings::whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($categoryId) {
            $q->where('id', $categoryId);
        })
        ->whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
            $q->where('id', $userId);
        })
        ->get();
}
```

To make this work, fix your relationships. Looks like all relations should be `belongsToMany()` and not `hasMany()`

Comment: Thank you for the hint. See my solution above :) @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: I did voted your answer. but I don't know how to choose the answer as the best one. I am happy to do it for yours :)

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the relationships in my Setting model to:

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'setting_user','setting_id', 'user_id');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Categories::class,'setting_category','category_id','setting_id');
}
```

I still have the belongsToMany relationship in my User model :

```
 public function settings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Setting::class, 'setting_user', 'user_id','setting_id');
}
```

And I have created another method to extract the Avatar which has id of "1" like so :

```
/**
* Get user's avatar.
*/
public function getAvatarAttribute() {

    $categoryId = 1;
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

    $avatar = $this->settings()->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($categoryId) {
        $q->where('id', $categoryId);
    })->whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
        $q->where('id', $userId);
    })->first();

    if(!$avatar)
    {
        return "default-avatar.jpg"; 
    }

    return $avatar->value;

}
```